# Translate character commands to SQL with translate_sql()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following character `"column == 5"` which I want to translate into sql: `column = 5`. How do I do this?

I have tried unsuccessfully numerous ways such as below:

```
translate_sql(eval(parse(text="column + 5")))
```

but translate_sql is a 'literal' environment and this returns `<SQL> EVAL(PARSE('column + 5' AS "text"))`.

I know there has got to be some trick to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call “‘literal’ environment” is generally known as a function with non-standard evaluation (NSE). In general there are different ways to work around them, but ‹dplyr› makes this easy by providing standard-evaluation companions to all NSE functions.

The standard-evaluation form of `translate_sql` is called `translate_sql_`:

```
translate_sql_("column + 5")
```

Furthermore, it’s often easier to go the direct way, rather than parsing a string input:

```
translate_sql_(quote(column + 5))
```

In your case there’s no great difference, but in many cases the form at the bottom is more useful since it’s an R object which can be manipulated using R methods. Manipulating a string input so that it still remains syntactically correct is much harder (and, unsurprisingly, less efficient).